# ExpandableListView in Android 2.1+

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, expandablelistview

Is ExpandableListView available in Android 2.1+ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html) says since api 1